# Is there any concept of load balancing in MySQL master-master architecture?

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, haproxy

I am running a MySQL 5.5 Master-Slave setup. For avoiding too many hits on my master server, I am thinking of having one or may be more servers for MySQL and incoming requests will first hit the HAProxy and it accordingly forwards the requests either in round robin or any scheduling algorithm defined in HAProxy. So set up will be like -

```
  APP -> API Gateaway/Server -> HAProxy -> Master Server1/Master Server2
```

So what can be pros and cons to this setup ?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Questions like this fit better on [dba.se]

Answer (score 2):

Replication in MySQL is asynchronous by default, so you can't always assume that the replicas are in sync with their source.

If you intend to use your load-balancer to split writes over the two master instances, you could get into trouble with that because of MySQL's asynchronous replication.

Say you commit a row on master1 to a table that has a unique key. Then you commit a row with the same unique value to the same table on master2, before the change on master1 has been applied through replication. Both servers allowed the row to be committed, because as far as they knew, it did not violate the unique constraint. But then as replication tries to apply the change on each server, those changes do conflict with the row committed. This is called *split-brain*, and it's incredibly difficult to recover from.

If your load-balancer randomly sends some read queries to another instance, they might not return data that you just committed on the other instance. This is called *replication lag*.

This may or may not be a problem for your app, but it's likely that in your app, at least *some* of the queries require strong consistency, i.e. reading outdated results is not permitted. Other cases even with the same app may be more tolerant of some replication lag.

I wrote a presentation some years ago about splitting queries between source and replica MySQL instances: https://www.percona.com/sites/default/files/presentations/Read%20Write%20Split.pdf. The presentation goes into more details about the different types of tolerance for replication lag.

MySQL 8.0 has introduced a more sophisticated solution for all of these problems. It's called Group Replication, and it does its best to ensure that all instances are in sync all the time, so you don't have the risk of reading stale data or creating write conflicts. The downside of Group Replication is that to ensure no replication lag occurs, it may need to constrain your transaction throughput. In other words, COMMITs may be blocked until the other instances in the replication cluster respond.

Read more about Group Replication here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html

P.S.: Whichever solution you decide to pursue, I recommend you do upgrade your version of MySQL. MySQL 5.5 passed its end-of-life in 2018, so it will no longer get updates even for security flaws.